# Does S tapping do more knockback than other forms of sprint resetting on Hypixel?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-bedwars

On one of Intel Edits videos, he said that S tapping was incredibly powerful on Bedwars because it does an insane amount of knockback  (video time is 2:53).

I specifically use W tapping, and was led to believe that W tapping, S tapping, and Block Hitting were all equal in regards to sprint resetting except that Block Hitting caused u to lose less movement.

So is S tapping better than W tapping for dealing knockback on Hypixel/Bedwars?

thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S tapping and W-tapping do the same amount of knockback because they both reset your sprint. There's no difference in kb. However, depending on the kind of s tapping you're using, you could also be moving out of your opponent's range by moving backwards. Mostly, S-tapping is better for starting combos by giving you more reach, and w-tapping is better for keeping them because it's just easier to do.